# Filter Function not working or recognized in VBA Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to filter an array in VBA by using the [filter function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/filter-function). But every time I try to execute the code, I get an error message

> Compile error:
> Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assign

for some reason. I copied some code from an external source to test it out, but even the simplest example doesn't seem to work. Here's the code:

```
Private Sub Befehl0_Click()
Dim langs(5) As Variant

langs(0) = "English"
langs(1) = 375
langs(2) = "Spanish"
langs(3) = 442
langs(4) = "Chinese"
langs(5) = 1299.5

output_arr = Filter(langs, 375)

End Sub
```

Every time I execute the code, the function "Filter" gets highlighted. Does anyone know the answer to this problem?

Comment: What about `output_arr = VBA.Filter(langs, 375)`?

Comment: Also, the 2nd argument should be a string, not a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works if I try `output_arr = VBA.Filter(langs, 375)` as BigBen has stated in the comments!